# Can't persist child entry with one to many relationship

Tags: hibernate, one-to-many, many-to-one

I have 3 entities, one is User:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "Users")
public class User {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name = "id")
    private int id;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinColumn(name = "schoolId", referencedColumnName = "id", nullable = false)
    private School school;

    @Column(name = "emailAddress", nullable = false, unique=true)
    private String emailAddress;

    @Column(name = "name", nullable = false)
    private String name;

    @Column(name = "pwd", nullable = false)
    private String password;

    @Column(name = "role", nullable = false)
    private int role;

    @ManyToMany(fetch=FetchType.EAGER, cascade = { CascadeType.ALL })
    @JoinTable(name = "Enrollment", joinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "userId") }, inverseJoinColumns = {
            @JoinColumn(name = "courseId") })
    private Set<Course> courses;

    @OneToMany(fetch=FetchType.EAGER, mappedBy = "user", cascade = { CascadeType.ALL })
    private Set<Post> posts;
    ...
```

One is Course:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "Courses")
public class Course {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name = "id")
    private int id;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinColumn(name = "schoolId", referencedColumnName = "id", nullable = false)
    private School school;

    @Column(name = "code", nullable = false)
    private String code;

    @Column(name = "name", nullable = false)
    private String name;

    @ManyToMany(fetch=FetchType.EAGER, cascade = { CascadeType.ALL })
    @JoinTable(name = "Enrollment", joinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "courseId") }, inverseJoinColumns = {
            @JoinColumn(name = "userId") })
    private Set<User> users;

    @OneToMany(fetch=FetchType.EAGER, mappedBy = "course", cascade = { CascadeType.ALL })
    private Set<Post> posts;
    ...
```

and Post:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "Posts")
public class Post {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name = "id")
    private int id;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinColumn(name = "courseId", referencedColumnName = "id", nullable = false)
    private Course course;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinColumn(name = "userId", referencedColumnName = "id", nullable = false)
    private User user;

    @Column(name = "title", nullable = false)
    private String title;

    @Column(name = "content")
    private String content;

    @Column(name = "views", nullable = false)
    private int views;

    @Column(name = "importance", nullable = false)
    private int importance;

    @Column(name = "createdAt", nullable = false)
    private Date createdAt;

    @Column(name = "updatedAt")
    private Date updatedAt;
    ...
```

The relationships between them are:

Post - n:1 -> Course

Post - n:1 -> User

What I'm trying to do is to add a new post in the database and update related course and user entry. Below is my code:

```
Configuration configuration = new Configuration();
        configuration.configure("hibernate.cfg.xml");
        SessionFactory sessionFactory = configuration.buildSessionFactory();
        Session session = sessionFactory.openSession();
        Transaction transaction = session.beginTransaction();
        User user = session.load(User.class, (Integer) this.session.get("userId"));
        Course course = session.load(Course.class, (Integer) this.session.get("courseId"));
        Post post = new Post();
        post.setContent(content);
        post.setCreatedAt(new Date());
        post.setTitle(title);
        post.setViews(0);
        post.setImportance(0);
        user.getPosts().add(post);
        course.getPosts().add(post);
        session.persist(user);
        session.persist(course);
        transaction.commit();
        session.close();
        sessionFactory.close();
```

When the code executed, here is the error I got:

1: not-null property references a null or transient value : com.qury.models.Post.course

2: org.hibernate.PropertyValueException: not-null property references a null or transient value : com.qury.models.Post.course

Where did I get it wrong? Should I set the user and course attribute of the post entity too?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It simple - *transient* value means something that's not yet part of the database. Those are usually newly created objects just like your `Post post = new Post();` So instead of adding these transient objects to other entities' list just add the other entities **which are returned from the database and therefore not transient** to the Post entity.

In other word turn this:

```
user.getPosts().add(post);
course.getPosts().add(post);
session.persist(user);
session.persist(course);
```

into this:

```
post.setUser(user);
post.setCourse(course);
session.persist(post);
```